# orange in anaconda does not get installed, can anyone help me?

Tags: anaconda, orange

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNPmN.png)
i have been trying to download orange, and also whenever it got downloaded it gives me an error saying that application is not responding. Orange started behaving weirdly on my PC some days back.
Now, after trying to download Orange on anaconda, after re-installing anaconda, the problem doesn't resolve. It shows that orange is downloading, but even after 30 mins it still shows downloading, which is not a wifi problem, I can vouch for it, that it is not.
downloading orange, and orange getting downloaded, but it didn't get downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I have Anaconda3-0.10 installed on my Windows 10 Machine.
I tried to install Orange from Anaconda Navigator, the installation fails/halts.

Installing Orange (3.14) Standalone did not work either, the installation fails with error.

For experimenting, I removed Anaconda, and installed Orange standalone, it took some time but it was successfully installed and it is working properly. Orange installed miniconda separately during the process.

After installing standalone Orange, I reinstalled the full version Anaconda, and it worked fine.

Apparently, there was a conflict somewhere when Anaconda is installed prior to installing Orange, therefore, as a fast workaround, trying removing Anaconda, install Orange, then reinstall Anaconda.